Newer headers not booting with Gigabyte motherboard
I have a Gigabyte B450m, and the latest header files will not load past boot. Does anybody have the same issue?
Newer header doesn't work:

Older header version works:


It would help to help you if you give the kernel info of the kernel giving the error.

Is your firmware up to date for the 450?  Check that all necessary compilers are present (check /proc/version for the compiler and that is is installed).

Linux version 6.5.0-10-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-118) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.41) #10-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri O>
6.5.0-25 (or any other version after 6.5.0-10) doesn't boot. I haven't updated the bios, afraid to break the system completely if I mess with that

Odd seeing gcc-13, my Ubuntu 22.04 hwe 6.5.0-35 kernel uses gcc-12. Which kernels are installed and which is the default? At least check your firmware release number against the release notes of later offerings to see what problems have been fixed.
